# str_to_date() does not work on right syntax

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I am trying to casting text from type to date type to sort desc.

```
select str_to_date('FRI 12 MAY', '%a %e %b');
```

It returns null even though it is correct syntax I think.

Is there any problem on my setting in mysql? or just syntax error?

Comment: Just your [syntax I think](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) _If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning_

Comment: Actually that gives me `0000-05-12`, which is not surprising as there is no year on the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really is good to read the manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

> Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to 0:

But then...

> If the [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) or [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) SQL mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed. In that case, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and generates a warning

---

So to fix this, you could either change your settings or add a dummy year:

```
select str_to_date(concat('12 MAY', ' 2000'), '%e %b %Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that with a valid year  (and then build a complete date) work

```
select str_to_date('Fri 12 May 2019', '%a %e %b %Y') ;
```